# Specify the main class when run spring-boot in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot

Now I am using eclipse to develop my spring-boot application .

I've 2 main classes for different purpose, but when I start one of them (in eclipse ) , the framework detected them both then start them one by one.

I knew that I can specify the only main class in the POM with maven goal spring-boot:run to make it as a Jar then specify the main class in command line parameter.

But any one please tell me **how to run the only specified main class with "eclipse run" when I am now in development phase.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<properties>
    <start-class>blah.blah.mainClass</start-class>
</properties>
```

Comment: thank you for your quick response , but what if I am start the main class by eclipse instead of maven run ?

Comment: please specify it for gradle

Comment: springBoot {
    mainClass = "demo.Application"
}